# protractor- browser.wait for text appear in cell

Tags: protractor

how can i wait that a string appears in some cell of a table using protractor?. Right now im doing:

```
let link = element(by.cssContainingText('.table >.table-row .c3', '/^test$/'));
      browser.wait(ec.presenceOf(link), 20000);
```

But im not getting the expected result. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `textToBePresentInElement()` method

```
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(yourElement, 'text in element'), 5000);
```

Comment: The problem is that i have many rows and many cells in table, and the text can appear in any cell with class '.c3'.  I think textToBePresentInElement doesnt work with array of elements

Answer (score 0):

If the text that will appear in the cell would be unique. u can try the below option

```
const ele = $('//Your text here');
awiat browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(ele), 5000, The wait for text to appear);
```

I have not tried it. Sorry if it does not helps you.